# Display y coordinate values with interactive cursor crosshairs in Python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below I have simple code that creates a scatter plot which includes an interactive cursor crosshair that moves with the mouse:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

x, y = 4*(np.random.rand(2, 100)-.5)
ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)

# set useblit = True on gtkagg for enhanced performance
cursor = Cursor(ax, useblit=True, color='black', linewidth=.5 )

plt.show()
```

I would like to add a feature to this code such that whenever I move the cursor, the y value (and x value if possible) is shown on the corresponding axis, right at the end of the hair.  Is this possible?

I've found an example image that somewhat depicts what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: crosshair example]

Comment: [This demo code](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/misc/cursor_demo_sgskip.html) gives some ideas, including snapping to the data. Also interesting is the [mplcursors library](https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors). Note that displaying text inside the axis labels is less interesting in cases when not every dot has a corresponding label in both axes.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your comment!  However, the demo doesn't really give me what I want.  It prints the values in some random spot in the corner, but what I want is to have the labels actually on the axis.  Also, I don't want the crosshairs to snap to the data, I need it to just follow the cursor exactly and then display the x and y axis values on the labels.